# How do you describe this way of walking while bent forward?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

How do you describe this way of walking:

Walking while bending forwards:

- because you are in severe pain.
- because you want to pass somewhere stealthily/ silently and thus 
  try not to be seen.
- because your old or weak, so you cannot walk uptight.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also "stooped", "crouched"

Comment: to tiptoe is the verb to describe "to pass somewhere stealthily/ silently and thus try not to be seen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Hunched](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hunched)* (over)

(of a person) leaning forwards with their shoulders raised and their head down, or (of shoulders, etc) in the posture adopted by a hunched person

> . "Genevieve **hunched** her shoulders against the storm of sound and fury and struggled to imagine a worse sort of hell."

Author: Ari Marmell

> With their souls of patent leather, they come down the road.
>
> **Hunched** and nocturnal, where they breathe they impose,
>
> silence of dark rubber, and fear of fine sand.

- Federico Garcia Lorca

Comment: Thanks a lot,  @Gandalf. Can I say :" My grandpa entered the room hunched over."?

Comment: @Soudabeh absolutely. Works for me. Just be careful with the word hunch as it has another common definition, that of "intuition", but it is a noun.